# I'm having trouble styling an input button?

Tags: html, css

I have a button that I am using to style a user's file input. I've scoured StackOverflow, as well as Google search result looking for solutions. I couldn't find anything that didn't involve javascript, or using a background image to get around the issue.

I came pretty close to what I thought was a solution. I had a div for the button, and then I could overlay the input on to the button. The problem with this was that I couldn't put text on to the button. This was the code I used for that:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="" class="form_container">
    <div class="image_upload_link">
        <input type="file" name="profile_picture" id="image_input" placeholder="Test">
        <div class="file_label">Upload a Picture</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

In this example, you can click on the button, and the file dialog appears, but the label for the button is below button itself.

So I switched the places of the `<input>` and the `<div class="file_label">`. Then I had a button, with a label that was perfectly inside it, but the input was below the button. That's what I have in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/As8Vc/1/

How do I have a button where you can contain both the label and the input? I have already tried messing around with the `z-index` property, with no luck.

Comment: Use `margin-top: -24px;` for class `div.image_upload_link input`

Comment: Thanks! I don't even know how long I looked for a solution for that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `margin-top: -24px;` for class `div.image_upload_link input`

Hope this will solve your problem.